# Twilio audio input fails after locking and unlocking screen in iOS 11

Tags: twilio

### Update

Twilio's responded and have been able to reproduce it. A short-term fix is to listen for the window's `focus` event and ask for permissions again. This isn't great, since it only seems to work for screens locked for a short duration:

```
window.addEventListener('focus', event => {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: true });
});
```

The other disadvantage is that it will ask for the user's permission immediately upon focus even if they had previously denied or not yet been asked. They recommend tracking the state of whether or not the user has granted permission yet before calling the `getUserMedia` API on window focus.

As philnash mentions in the comments, this is likely an Apple bug due to the fact that it is demonstrated in locked screens of a long duration.

---

This question is about using the Twilio JS SDK to capture audio input and record it using TWIML.

Using the [twilio client quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/client/javascript), I'm getting intermittent results for successful audio capture. It seems related to some unstable browser state where the input stream cannot be read after locking and unlocking the screen.

I'd be happy to offer up the full code that I'm using, but AFAIK the only relevant change I've made is to the callback route, which now returns a `<Record>` TWIML verb.

```
// Create a TwiML voice response
const response = new VoiceResponse();
response.record({
    timeout: 10,
    transcribe: true,
    action: '/callback',
    maxLength: 180,
    recordingStatusCallback: '/callback',
});
return response.toString();
```

Any Twilio people out there who can help diagnose this? It's fairly straight forward to reproduce.

1. Follow the directions in the quick start guide
2. Load up the quickstart webpage iOS Safari
3. Lock and unlock the screen
4. Attempt to place a call (or record one using the TWIML above)

Audio input won't be captured. The OS *does* prompt you to allow permission to access the microphone.

If you attempt to place a call without the locking/unlocking behavior, when you tap the "Call" button, it works as expected. One difference I've noticed is that a red microphone icon appears in the browser bar, indicating that the browser is using audio, I presume. In the other case, no icon is visible.

The only way to restore the client to work again is to fully close the tab and load up a fresh tab. Refreshing doesn't work.

Any thoughts or feedback on this situation would be wonderful! It's very possible this is an Apple bug, but I figured I'd see if you all had any insight you might want to share.

Comment: My guess here is that this is more to do with iOS Safari's `getUserMedia` implementation and permissions. I imagine it's possible to recreate this with just the native APIs. I don't know how to fix it though. Hoping that others in the community might have seen this before and know what to do.

Comment: Twilio support offered a minor fix that calls `getUserMedia` on the window `focus` event, but that only seems to fix it for screens locked for a short duration, maybe 30s or 1m. Longer locked screens exhibit the same behavior. FWIW their engineer have identified this as an SDK issue and I have a support ticket. I'll repost here with more updates.

Comment: That was my suggestion ;) That it worked for a short duration and not on subsequent locks either suggests to me that it's a Safari problem which we may be able to workaround.

Comment: oh hi! nice to see you here. I was thinking it might have something to do with manually selecting the audio input, but I'm not that well versed in the tangled web of the web audio api. fingers crossed someone somewhere sees this. Any tips for how I might be able to raise this with Apple?

Comment: Oh, also on your update, I suggested that you maintain state of whether you've already asked for permissions for mic access and only make the auto re-ask if you'd already asked. But still, it doesn't help that much.

Comment: Yeah I agree that it doesn't help that much if it only works for the first lock/unlock pattern, but I'll tweak the update to include that thought regardless.

Comment: Heh, yeah. You weren't talking directly with me, but I was trying to help out behind the scenes (and now in front of them). For raising bugs with apple there is this form: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/. I also asked on Twitter for help here and tried to nudge one of the web technologies evangelists for Apple to see if he can help: https://twitter.com/philnash/status/915223154074820609

Comment: I replied to your tweet and then realized I wanted to quote it, so that happened. I'll be filing a bug with apple next. Thanks for responding!